# Django, Error 404, Not Found: /products/5

Tags: django, django-urls

I have quation regarding Django, I tried to solve it myself during 2 days, but need some help.
I read a book about Django, and there is example:
urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^products/?P<productid>\d+/', views.contact),
    re_path(r'^users/(?P<id>\d+)/?P<name>\D+/', views.about),
    re_path(r'^about/contact/', views.contact),
    re_path(r'^about', views.about),
    path('', views. index),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Main</h2>")


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>About site</h2>")


def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Contacts</h2>")


def products(request, productid):
    output = "<h2>Product № {0}</h2>".format(productid)
    return HttpResponse(output)


def users(request, id, name):
    output = "<h2>User</h2><h3>id: {О} " \
                   "Name:{1}</hЗ>".format(id, name)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

But after using this link `http://127.0.0.l:8000/products/5`, I get this text:

```
Using the URLconf defined in hello.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 
^products/?P<productid>\d+/
^users/(?P<id>\d+)/?P<name>\D+/
^about/contact/
^about
The current path, products/5, didn’t match any of these.
```

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

And this thing in terminal:

> Not Found: /products/5
> [08/Feb/2023 12:17:13] "GET /products/5 HTTP/1.1" 404 2597

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this solution myself yet - but it looks like you're missing some parentheses. Also the product mapping is wrong (should be `views.products` instead of `views.contact`).

I believe the first path you've configured should be something like:

```
re_path(r'^products/(?P<productid>\d+)/', views.products),
```

This should work, but will match `products/5` as well as `products/5/anything/else/here` which is probably not the behaviour you're after. In that case the path should be something like:

```
re_path(r'^products/(?P<productid>\d+)/$', views.products),
```

The django docs do a pretty good job at explaining how all this works in any level of detail you need, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#re-path

Comment: I have written this code, wcich you had sent to me, but now I have this problem:

Comment: TypeError at /products/5/
contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'productid'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/5/
Django Version: 4.1.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'productid'
Exception Location: C:\Users\kiril\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 197, in _get_response
Raised during: firstapp.views.contact
Python Executable: C:\Users\kiril\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.1

Comment: Because `contact` is not the view you wanted to call here. Fix mapping to views.product in the url patter.

Comment: What @IvanStarostin said is correct - I missed that error too. I've edited my response to have the correct code